# Google's SDTT doesn't figure out my location

Tags: schema.org, microdata, google-rich-snippets

I have just started trying to get my head around using Schema.org. I have customised a bit of schema into the text in my website footer (on WordPress).

When I test my page with [Google Structured Data Testing Tool](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/), it's coming back as errors and I need to figure out why.

I live in Wareham, Dorset, UK but the Google tool doesn't seem to recognise my location?

My Microdata is as follows:

```html
    <div itemscope itemtype=”http://schema.org/ProfessionalService“>
    <link itemprop=”additionalType” href=”http://www.productontology.org/doc/Wedding_photography” />
    <b><span style="color:#88cccf; font-size: 15pt" itemprop="member" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">Velvet Bliss   Photography</span></b><br>
    <em>Photography by <span itemprop="name">Brett McNally</span></em><br>  <br>
    <div>
    I am a professional freelance <span itemprop="jobtitle">photographer</span> based in <span itemprop=”address”   itemscope itemtype=”http://schema.org/PostalAddress”>
    <span itemprop=”addressLocality”>Wareham</span>,
    <span itemprop=”addressRegion”>Dorset</span>. I provide <span   itemprop=”name”>Wedding Photography</span> & <span itemprop=”name”>Portrait   Photography</span> services in Dorset and I take on commissions for wedding   photography all over the <span itemprop="addressCountry">UK</span>, as well as   internationally for destination weddings.
    </div><br>
    <div>Contact me: <span itemprop=”telephone”>07470 201325</span>
    </div>
    <link rel="author"   href="https://plus.google.com/u/0/117967472486546237170">
    <link rel="publisher"  https://plus.google.com/u/0/114441860370278522542">
    <br>
    <em><span style="font-size: 9pt">You can also find me on these social media websites:</span></em>
```

Here in the UK, my address is:

> Town / City: *Wareham*
>
> County: *Dorset*

but schema doesn't seem to recognise that we are on the map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see! It was not obvious first, but I think I have found the issue it was non standard quotation marks. I replaced them and then tested in Google testing tool and now it is showing all green (just one tag i.e. jobtitle not part of professional entity) otherwise all schema recognized, test this please:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ProfessionalService">
<link itemprop="additionalType" href="http://www.productontology.org/doc/Wedding_photography" />
<b><span style="color:#88cccf; font-size: 15pt" itemprop="member" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">Velvet Bliss   Photography</span></b><br>
<em>Photography by <span itemprop="name">Brett McNally</span></em><br>  <br>
<div>
I am a professional freelance <span itemprop="jobtitle">photographer</span> based in <span itemprop="address"   itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
<span itemprop="addressLocality">Wareham</span>,
<span itemprop="addressRegion">Dorset</span>. I provide <span   itemprop="name">Wedding Photography</span> & <span itemprop="name">Portrait   Photography</span> services in Dorset and I take on commissions for wedding   photography all over the <span itemprop="addressCountry">UK</span>, as well as   internationally for destination weddings.
</div><br>
<div>Contact me: <span itemprop="telephone">07470 201325</span>
</div>
<link rel="author"   href="https://plus.google.com/u/0/117967472486546237170">
<link rel="publisher"  https://plus.google.com/u/0/114441860370278522542">
<br>
<em><span style="font-size: 9pt">You can also find me on these social media websites:</span></em>
```